# Yii url rewrite url using urlManager?

Tags: php, yii

this my controller file MyController.php

```
class MyController extends CController
{
    /**
     * Index action is the default action in a controller.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->printtablerecord();
        $this->abc();
    }
    public function print(){
        echo "print";
    }
    public function abc(){
        echo "abc";

    }
    public function abc1(){
        echo "abc1";
    }

}
```

when i run this file domain.com/mypage/index.php  call this controller.

but i want to run the domain.com/mypage/index.php/abc it's return 404.

i want to run controller function with url.

when i run domain.com/mypage/index.php/mycontroller/functionname

that run my specific function using url.

how to write rules into main.php using urlManager?

this is my config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
                'abc' => 'MyController/abc',
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
public function print(){
    echo "print";
}
```

to:

```
public function actionPrint(){
    echo "print";
}
```

and also you can hide index.php too:http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7803-how-to-remove-index-php-from-url/

Answer (score 1):

You have to changes these function name as action. like abcAction,abc1Action,printAction

Read This http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller

Comment: naveen it's not working. i try to run after changing name but i got 404.

Comment: can u share url which one u trying and controller code for this action?

Comment: actionPrint not printAction guys!